# Alter the appearance of glossary entries

Tags: glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package and want to change the format used, so that the full stops after entry descriptions and before the page number reference aren't added automatically. This cause problems when including enumerated lists in glossary entries, as I need to do. An entry like this:

```
\newglossaryentry{test}{name={test}, description={

\begin{enumerate}
\item one, 
\item two, and
\item three
\end{enumerate}}, sort=Derived} 
}
```

appears as

```
1) one,
2) two, and
3) three

. N
```

where `N` is the page number. So I want to know if I can alter the format so that I have to add in full stops myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed to alter `\glspostdescription`:

```
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeglossaries
```